# Result of Grover on Qiskit simulator

Tags: qiskit, measurement, grovers-algorithm

I have executed this circuit and I don't understand why the result is $|11\rangle$ ?

- `[q[0], q[1]]` : solution register
- `[q[2]]` : ancilla register (clause value)
- `[q[3]]` : boolean value of Oracle function

[image: Circuit]

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I add a "ghost qubit" in the solution space in order to increase *N*. I fixe the "ghost qubit" to a state (|1> here) and we get *#solutions < N/2*

[image: The circuit]

[image: The results]

Answer (score 0):

3 out of 4 states are inverted, that leads to the following situation before you do the Grover Diffusion, which mirror around the red line:

[image]

This will bring the all states to zeros, but not $|11\rangle$...

Comment: So, i think it's because the number of solutions is greater than N/2 ?
How can I fix it if it's possible ?

Comment: @julienrodriguez what do you expect from the circuit? What are you looking for? Do you know what would happen if the number is exactly N/2? –

Comment: this circuit compute a simple 2-sat formula (not a or not b). I see https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5318/grover-algorithm-for-more-than-one-element before my ask.

Comment: @julienrodriguez I'm not sure if this will really help you, since you're dealing with a special case.