# How to find all marked items by quantum search algorithm(Grover's algorithm)?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm

We know that the Grover algorithm outputs a marked item. Now we want to know the locations of all items. I can't find any paper to solve this problem.

Comment: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5318/11793 is perhaps relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Grover's search returns a uniform superposition of all marked items. So, yes, in your last step, you measure it and find a random sample out of that set. If you want others, just repeat and you'll get another random sample.

If you want to be a bit more directed, you can explicitly exclude any items you've previously found by unmarking them in your oracle step.